# While my react app running in jenkins "nohup npx serve -s build -p 3006 &"command doesnot work where it works manually in bash

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

While my react app running in jenkins
`nohup npx serve -s build -p 3006 &` command does not work where it works manually in bash.

I am using windows shell in build section where the above command is not running.